# debus-monitor output reading

Tags: python, ubuntu, triggers

I am trying to trigger the python script or shell script whenever a desktop notification has arrived  using dbus-monitor

I am using the command in this way

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered "string" | xargs -I '{}'  python3 ./test.py {}
```

after that, I am trying to send the desktop notification from another terminal using
-> notify-send "hello" "world"

the output for the above custom notification is

```
string "notify-send"
string ""
string "hello"
string "world "
      string "urgency"
string "notify-send"
string ""
string "hello"
string "world "
      string "urgency"
```

but if my output of this command is 10 lines, then the python script is getting called for every line.

but my expectation is to call the python script once for every notification and then get all the output in a single line as a param for the python script.

Answer (score 1):

It is wise to take advantage of `systemd` integration with `dbus`.

Using `systemd` integration the programmer has better controls/sensors over the `dbus` integration. Also can take advantage on `systemd` loging/monitors mechanisms.

There is a good article [here](https://trstringer.com/python-systemd-dbus/) about systemd dbus with python..

Also there is very related answer to your question in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309250/how-to-globally-monitor-systemd-unit-states). as well.